# How to convert LatLng[] to string[] in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQoIm.jpg)

am using xamarin android in google map direction getting multiple latlan values, so i want to store those values in mysql db, here am trying to convert latlng array values to string array to store datatable, so please anyone can give sample code for this problem

Comment: Extract the values of Latitude and Longitude and `toString()` them? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select()`:

```
var res = 
     latLngArray.Select(i => i.Latitude.ToString() + "," + i.Longitude.ToString())
                .ToArray();
```